# Stata: density/distribution functions with survey data

Tags: histogram, distribution, stata, survey

I have a problem in Stata. I have a survey dataset with sampling weights and stratification. Calculating population totals can be done very easily by first set up the survey design (sampling weights and strata) and then using the prefix svy: total. But unfortunately it is not possible to plot density functions using histogram since it ignores the survey design. Is there any way to plot density and distribution functions of population totals easily with survey data?

Comment: in R the `survey` package has a `?svyplot` feature

Comment: Show us the Stata code you would have used to solve your problem if the data had not come from a survey sample.

Comment: For example: `hist height`. Very simple. `hist` has only the option of using frequency weights (you can only use integers), not pweights.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm guessing that you have divided height, or another variable, into categories; used **svy total** to get the category totals , and would like to have a histogram of those. Is this right?  If by "density", you mean  "probability density function", then the non-survey Stata command is **kdensity**.  If by "distribution function",  you mean "cumulative distribution function", the non-survey command is **cumul**.  Are you also trying to emulate these commands?

Answer (score 1):

The **histogram**, **kdensity**, and **cumul** commands all take frequency weights, which must be integers.  The problem with sampling weights is that they can be non-integral.  However you can create frequency weights that will be multiples of the probability weights and agree in precision to any desired accuracy. (The trick is due to Austin Nichols.) This will permit you do use the above commands. <s>The only option unavailable will be the **frequency** option of **histogram**.</s>  The other functions are means, so are invariant to multiplication of the original weights.

In this example, I use  the nhanes2b data set. It turns out that all the weights are integers, so the conversion trick isn't needed.

```
 webuse nhanes2b, clear

/* Create frequency weight which
agrees with original weight to any degree of accuracy */

local k = 2 
/* Match sampling weights to k = 2 decimal places:
   e.g. sampling weight = 3.212 -> fwt =321 */ 
gen fwt = round(10^(`k')*finalwgt,1)

/* 1. Histogram */
histogram height [fw = fwt], percent width(10)
/* 2. Probability Density */
kdensity height [fw = fwt], bwidth(2)


/*  3. CDF  */
cumul height [fw = fwt], gen(cum)
sort height cum
scatter cum height, c(J) ms(i)
```

**Edit: histogram with frequency option:**

This uses the undocumented command `twoway__histogram_gen` (http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0014).

```
  twoway__histogram_gen height [fw = fwt], ///
     freq  width(10) gen(h x, replace)
  replace  h = round( h/10^`k')/10^6
  format h %5.0f
  twoway bar h x, ///
      bstyle(histogram) barwidth(10) ///
      ytitle("Frequency (Millions)")
```

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely correct that my variables are categorised and then weighted. But one aspect is unclear to me. What do you mean by: "The only option unavailable will be the frequency option of histogram" since you used frequency weights for creating histograms?

Comment: "frequency" will show weighted numbers of observations. These will be off by the multiple of 10 that was used to create the frequency weights:  with k = 2, for example a probability weighted count of 5,000 will appear as 500,000.

Comment: True, the values will be multiples, however the relation among the values will be the same. I found another solution suggested by Heeringa, West and Berglund (2010) to simply use the integer part of the sampling weight:
`gen int_weight=int(weight)`. 
Still, I do not fully understand why Stata does not offer histograms with pweights...

Comment: Actually, Heeringa's solution rounds down, which can lead to inaccuracies with small weights. Better would be:
`gen fwt = round(weight)` which rounds to the nearest integer, but that is exactly Austin's solution for `k =0`.

For completeness, I've edited my answer to show how  get `histogram, freq` with correct labels for the multiplied weights.